# Bash regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash

How to delete all files in the current dir - but not those which have `1.65` in the title?

I tried to capture such files with

```
*[^1][^\.][^6][^5]*
*[^\(1\.65\)]*
```

(one can press `Alt-*` to expand the regexp)

but it doesn't work. Here's a code for experiments:

```
touch foo1.65bar \#bla1.66 qbit0.65t 1.65boris notRelated@All
```

Comment: As an aside, regular expressions don't work like that.  If there is a way to make it match, the regex will find it, and report a match.  So for your regex example, the regex engine will find that foo1.65bar matches because `f` matches `[^1]`, and the first `o` matches `[^.]` (no need for a backslash there, btw), and the second `o` matches `[^6]`, and `1` matches `[^5]`.  This is also sort of the explanation to why there are different regex engines and why globbing doesn't use regex; each tool is adapted to a particular purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is often more reliable and expressive to use find for such jobs:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 '(' -type f -and -not -name '*1\.65*' ')' -delete
```

Comment: @unbeli: Fair enough. I just tend to put them whenever `-delete` is on the line to make sure `find` uses *my* idea of the order of operator precedence.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [extended globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) ..(bash 4)

```
touch a b c foo1.65bar foo1_65bar
ls  
echo ======
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*1.6*)
ls
```

Output

```
a  b  c  foo1_65bar  foo1.65bar
=====
foo1.65bar
```

Comment: Thanks I never heard of that. From one point of view - it's cool to have a support for regular expressions. From the other - it is bad to be having to learn one more regular expression concept - why woudn't them just conform to [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcre).

Comment: @Adobe. I'd assume that it is because `bash` had to adapt this extended globbing to an existing framework which would break if regex was implemented as per PCRE..

Comment: @Adobe it's because PCRE is too different from normal shell globbing, and would be very confusing to have shell matching suddenly behave completely different from normal.  For example, if you typed `foo.txt` as an argument and PCRE matching was in effect, it'd match the period to any single character (equivalent to `foo?txt` in normal globbing). `*.txt`, on the other hand, is an invalid RE because `*` means "0 or more of the last thing", and at the beginning of the pattern there's no "last thing".

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like the one below on a filename with Ruby, Python, Perl, etc. You then have to write a little script or one liner in the chosen language to do the job. It uses negative lookahead. Cfr. [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^((?!1\.65).)*$
```

When you want to build a regex that won't match a specific string, you can't use `[]` because it specifies individual characters, not all of them in sequence. You have to use lookaround constructs.

Comment: Well - this is kind of too hard for me. But thanks for the information anyway.